# gwt-maven-plugin: How to set system properties for the gwt:run goal in the pom.xml?

Tags: gwt, maven-2

I'm trying to set a system property on a GWT application running in hosted mode launched using `mvn gwt:run`. The property isn't getting set, by the looks of things. In my `pom.xml` the plugin configuration is: -

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <configuration>
        <module>com.foo</module>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
    <systemProperties>
      <property>
        <name>configDir</name>
        <value>${basedir}/local/staging</value>
      </property>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Compile Guide](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/compile.html) for gwt-maven-plugin.  You can use the `extraJvmArgs` element.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k -Dfoo=bar</extraJvmArgs>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Edit: This turned out not to work for the `gwt:run goal`, but moving the extraJvmArgs into the plugin (rather than execution) configuration did: -

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k -Dfoo=bar</extraJvmArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This didn't work for the run goal, but adding the `extraJvmArgs` element as a child of `plugin` (rather than `execution`) does work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

systemProperties are not properties but a map

Use it like this :

```
<systemProperties>
      <configDir>${basedir}/local/staging</configDir> 
</systemProperties>
```

Comment: how is a configDir a map?