# How would I give the GWT-compiler more memory when using GWT-Maven?

Tags: gwt, maven, gwt-compiler, gwt-maven-plugin

We have a Maven build that runs the GWT plugin (gwt-maven).  Unfortently it is running out of memory.

Do I need to give Maven itself more heap or do I need to give GWT more heap? Any idea how to specify this for a pom.xml file?

Answer (score 5):

I assume [`extraJvmArgs`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#extraJvmArgs) option should be configured.

Comment: Example: set MAVEN_OPTS=-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xms1g -Xmx2g"

Answer (score 5):

Add extraJvmArgs tag under configuration tag for gwt-maven-plugin.

Example -

```
        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>app.html</runTarget>
                <!-- Turning This on after understanding soyc and when deferredjs count is 48.cache.js -->
                <!-- https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/fragment_merging -->
                <fragmentCount>25</fragmentCount>
                -->
                <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                <!-- Turn This on for generating soyc. This does not work if closure compiler is turned on.-->
                <!-- Start Generating SOYC -->
                <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                <compilerMetrics>true</compilerMetrics>
                <soycDetailed>true</soycDetailed>
                <!-- End Generating SOYC -->
                <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
                <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
                <enableClosureCompiler>true</enableClosureCompiler>
                <optimizationLevel>9</optimizationLevel>
                <style>${gwt.style}</style>
                <module>${gwtModule}</module>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <hostedWebapp>
                    ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}
                </hostedWebapp>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx896M -Xms896m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</extraJvmArgs>
                <!-- <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx896M -Xms896m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -server</extraJvmArgs> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with a large GWT project. The error that you will probably see when running out of memory is:

```
[ERROR] OutOfMemoryError: Increase heap size of lower gwt.jjs.maxThreads
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The `extraJvmArgs` option needs to be set in conjunction with the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable ([this is a possible explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gwt-maven/sPEzPuYVpb4/By29tdV-l5cJ)). I also set the Java `-Dgwt.compiler.localWorkers=x` option to reduce the number of concurrent compilation threads (I set x to 1, but you can play with it to find something that works).

For an example of the settings you should use with the extraJvmArgs option, see this [post](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Advanced+Build+Notes#AdvancedBuildNotes-GWTCompilationMemoryRequirements).

Note that you may need to add the extraJvmArgs option to the plugin element configuration directly - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822929/157605.